# calculate Telerik RadDatePicker date difference using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to calculate number of days from the selected dates from the calendar controls.Could you please let me know if there are any functions in Javascript.

```
  <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dtStart" runat="server" Culture="English (United States)"
        MinDate="0001-01-01" Enabled="true">
        <DateInput ID="DateInput2" runat="server" DisplayDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy">
        </DateInput>
        <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="DateSelected" />
    </telerik:RadDatePicker>

    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dtEndDate" runat="server" Culture="English (United States)"
        MinDate="0001-01-01" Enabled="true">
        <DateInput ID="DateInput3" runat="server" DisplayDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy">
        </DateInput>
        <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="DateSelected" />
    </telerik:RadDatePicker>

function DateSelected(sender, eventArgs) {
    var startDate = $find('<%=dtStart.ClientID%>');
    var endDate =  $find('<%=dtEndDate.ClientID%>');

    if ((startDate.get_selectedDate() != null) && (endDate.get_selectedDate() != null)) {
        var days = (startDate.get_selectedDate() - endDate.get_selectedDate());  
    }
}
```

Comment: [new Date() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the `telerik:RadDatePicker` before, but I assume you can eventually get a JavaScript date from that.  Once you have that, you can do:

```
var timeDiffMS = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
var diffDays = Math.floor(timeDiffMS / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper library known as moment.js to subtract dates with javascript. http://momentjs.com/docs/